# How to get insights about a z3 query when not on Windows

Tags: fstar

The wiki page at https://github.com/FStarLang/FStar/wiki/Profiling-Z3-queries suggests using the Z3 Axiom Profiler; however, the Z3 Axiom Profiler seems to work reliably on Windows only.

How can I easily get the quantifiers that fire the most without the Z3 Axiom Profiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command-line invocation works fine enough for me, relies only on z3's qi.profile feature, and leaves the top offenders at the bottom.

```
z3 smt.qi.profile=true queries-EverCrypt.Hash.Incremental-33.smt2 |& grep quantifier_instances | sort -t : -k 2 -n
```

(edited following Nik's answer to remove z3 options now embedded in the smt2 file)

Answer (score 2):

Related to Jonathan's reply:

Since this commit: https://github.com/FStarLang/FStar/commit/c4ce03c3709b44600d66b8c2ee55a0e1aa9f75a3

It is sufficient to just run:

```
z3 smt.qi.profile=true queries-Foo.smt2
```

since the other F*-specific options are now embedded within the .smt2 file.

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to use the axiom profiler on Linux via `mono` but it does indeed take *many* hours (it appears to hang for a long time during this process, but it does indeed work). Once it has finished its analysis, the interface is quite responsive (although I would recommend staying away from a few of the options under the "File" menu which cause it to crash).

Since I would need to basically leave it overnight for non-trivial traces, I spin it up on a server and use X forwarding via [xpra](https://xpra.org/) (which allows me to disconnect and reconnect to the server).

---

If the issue is purely to find queries that are triggering badly, and if fstar works faster with hints, then I also have a useful script [`fstar-profile-queries`](https://github.com/jaybosamiya/dotfiles/blob/master/random-localbin-scripts/.local/bin/fstar-profile-queries)  that I'd written a few months ago that might be useful. It uses `qprofdiff` to find offending queries, but does it in a way that is much nicer to work with.